# OkHttp: NoSuchMethodError copyInto in TlsUtil

Tags: kotlin, okhttp

Running instrumentation tests with `RESTMock` we are getting this error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method copyInto$default([Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;IIIILjava/lang/Object;)[Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lkotlin/collections/ArraysKt; or its super classes (declaration of 'kotlin.collections.ArraysKt' appears in /data/app/com.example.debug-1/base.apk)
FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-6-thread-1
Process: com.example.debug, PID: 6606
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method copyInto$default([Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;IIIILjava/lang/Object;)[Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lkotlin/collections/ArraysKt; or its super classes (declaration of 'kotlin.collections.ArraysKt' appears in /data/app/com.example.debug-1/base.apk)
    at okhttp3.tls.internal.TlsUtil.newKeyManager(TlsUtil.kt:84)
    at okhttp3.tls.HandshakeCertificates$Builder.build(HandshakeCertificates.kt:144)
    at io.appflate.restmock.SslUtils.localhost(SslUtils.java:49)
    at io.appflate.restmock.RESTMockServer.setUpHttps(RESTMockServer.java:91)
    at io.appflate.restmock.RESTMockServer.init(RESTMockServer.java:74)
    at io.appflate.restmock.RESTMockServerStarter$1.run(RESTMockServerStarter.java:56)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
```

This is the line in question [in OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp-tls/src/main/java/okhttp3/tls/internal/TlsUtil.kt#L84)

IIUC, Kotlin can treat a `varargs` as a Kotlin Array and then call extensions functions like [copyInto](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/copy-into.html)

We're on OkHttp 4.0.1, Kotlin 1.3.40, R8 1.5.41

Our test apk correctly contains `copyInto` method so I don't think it's a proguard/R8 issue:

[image]

I'm at a loss as to what to test next. I asked on OkHttp's github issuse page and they suggested I post here [link](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/5308)

Update: still happening on OkHttp 4.1.0. Also I realized that it *can't* be an R8 issue since R8 doesn't remove code from test apk.

Comment: Could you possibly share your SslUtils code related in the trace?

Comment: could please share the related code in SslUtils.

Comment: @BrandonMcAnsh it's part of RestMock https://github.com/andrzejchm/RESTMock/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/appflate/restmock/SslUtils.java

Answer (score 8):

I had a same issue , then added the mentioning lib to my project. It solved my problem:

maven :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.70</version>
        </dependency>
```

or

```
'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.70'
```

Answer (score 6):

I got the same issue when I was using `okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer` with https enabled with a server certificate from `okhttp-tls`.
In my case, the problem was that by just importing the `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-tls:4.2.0` dependency, `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib` was being resolved to version `1.2.71`.
Given the `copyInto` method was introduced starting kotlin `1.3` it was failing with the same error you have.

I fixed it by adding explicitly the kotlin version in my gradle.build file:
`testRuntime 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.50'`

Comment: okhttp and okhttp-tls depend on 1.3.50, so something else must have been pinning it back to an old version.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/4.2.0

Comment: Hmm maybe I had a similar problem. When I came back to this problem a few weeks later it had been resolved. Likely I updated another lib that pulled us to the latest Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, but I'm developing a multi-module java project. It was useful that add a dependency for `kotlin-stdlib` in pom.xml that belongs to this module while unit testing...

When I boot this whole project, this issue came out agnain. Finally, I find this dependency need to be in the whole project's pom.xml, I mean the pom.xml in the project's root dir.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30235168)